# Looking for Python package to parse NACHA files

Tags: python, parsing, reader, banking

I am looking for a python package I can use to parse NACHA/ACH files and/or extract the data into a workable format. There are others in different languages but I need this one to be in Python. Even a package that could be worked into a larger solution to extract data from NACHA/ACH files would be great.

I believe that there should be something out there, but have only been able to find generators. Does anyone have a recommendation or even a package that could be worked on to fill this need?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use awk to parse a fixed-width (NACHA) file format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418997/how-do-i-use-awk-to-parse-a-fixed-width-nacha-file-format)

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't think so. Awk is a Linux command and my environment is on Windows. I also, again, need the solution to be in Python and preferably as a package.

Comment: Did you tried `py-nacha`. You can refer this link - https://pypi.org/project/py-nacha/

Comment: That worked for me thanks. It's a bit limited but I can run with it.

Comment: thats great..let me also add this as an answere